# USB connector pinout

Tags: usb

I am planning to use this USB connector but I am having trouble finding the pin-out:

https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/USB-A1SSW6/ED2991-ND/2677752

I checked 3-4 different manufacturers and all of them give just the drawing and package info. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Physical connector data sheets do not typically give the *role* of the pins but only the numbers.  The pins are numbered in the drawing.  The role of the pin numbers is in the USB spec and all over the net.  You merely need to put the two together.  If in doubt, wait to design the board until you have the part in hand and can verify it with an ohm meter.

Comment: As Chris Stratton said, the pinout is part of the USB specification. In this case, Wikipedia is very helpful - please see their USB page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB).

Comment: Thanks @bitsmack. Looks like 1,2,3,4 are named as +,D-,D+,- in general. Will design accordingly and as Chris pointed out, would rather check with a component before placing the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow USB spec. Here is an image showing the pin and nets:

[image]

Tie the shell to GND as well.

Datasheet has the pin numbering:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

USB pinout get confusing since there are many type available with different number of pins. I had a tough time finding answer for few question so i decided to leave them here so that it stays useful for other.

The most common USB female connector has 4 pins, this type of connector is called **Type-A female connector** and is used in **USB2.0** connections. The below image marks the pin out clearly 
[image: USB pinout - Type A / USB2.0]

For simple embedded interfaces this connector holds good, but the USB3.0 and type-C are catching up since they can transfer more current and offers small form factor. The maximum.The maximum current these Type-A connectors can handle is only 500mA

Image Source: [USB Pinout and detials](https://components101.com/connectors/usb-type-a-female)